# Open angular Powered bootstrap modal from another component

Tags: angular

I am newbie in Angular 4. Current I am in a situation to use agnular powered bootstrap in my application. 
(https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

For Now I want to open the bootstrap modal on a button click from  another page.
The parent page looks like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbdModalBasic }  from './modal-basic';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './addYourCargo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addYourCargo.component.css'],
})
export class addYourCargo {
    openModal(){

    }
}
```

NgbdModalBasic  is the modal compoenent and it looks like as follows

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: './modal-basic.html',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

and the modal HTML

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

      <hr>

      <pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

I have included the Modal component in the main module.ts file.

I am clicking a button from the parent component and it triggers openModal function. I have to Call the open function in the Modal component So that it can open modal by button click from parent component.

How can I proceed further. What should be done inside openModal function to open a modal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by calling a method on the modal that you access from other component (depends on the position of your components):

```
<button (click)="modal.openModal()">Open Modal</button>
<your-modal #modal></your-modal>
```

For more info, look at the Angular doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable)

Comment: @BodganC How can open a modal from Open a modal function. Because now I can just enter into that function. But from there is there any way to open a modal from there

Comment: You can do it the same way is done in the doc demo [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), just that you are going to call `open()` from another component, as in my answer.